# iOS only half of view displaying

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard

I have this problem. So I'm making this snapchat style menu with switching screens in a horizontal scroll view. All the view controllers are in 1 story board.

```
let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let V1 = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("FirstViewController")
let V2 = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SecondViewController")
let V3 = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ThirdViewController")
let V4 = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("FourthViewController")

self.addChildViewController(V1)
self.scrollView.addSubview(V1.view)
V1.didMoveToParentViewController(self)

self.addChildViewController(V2)
self.scrollView.addSubview(V2.view)
V2.didMoveToParentViewController(self)

self.addChildViewController(V3)
self.scrollView.addSubview(V3.view)
V3.didMoveToParentViewController(self)

self.addChildViewController(V4)
self.scrollView.addSubview(V4.view)
V4.didMoveToParentViewController(self)

var V2Frame : CGRect = V2.view.frame
V2Frame.origin.x = self.view.frame.width
V2.view.frame = V2Frame

var V3Frame : CGRect = V3.view.frame
V3Frame.origin.x = self.view.frame.width * 2
V3.view.frame = V3Frame

var V4Frame : CGRect = V4.view.frame
V4Frame.origin.x = self.view.frame.width * 3
V4.view.frame = V4Frame

self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.width * 4, self.view.frame.size.height)
```

However, as previously stated... only about half of each view shows....

Comment: Why aren't you using auto-layout? What device is this on and what size are your views on the storyboard?

Comment: Do you mean each viewcontroller is cut in half? Or that when you scroll it lands on a view of half of each?

Comment: @JulianLee When I scroll... only half of the view shows.

Comment: @Wain the views are full screen size...

Comment: @Wain.... the story board has the main view controller and others. The main view has a scroll view that has pagination enabled... the pages of the scroll view are the other views in the story board....

Comment: In what method is this code? What is the value of `self.view.frame.width`? Is it what you expect?

Comment: @beyowulf it's in the viewDidLoad method... and yeah the result is correct